# what could be wrong as there is no error displayed and the code isn't processed: enum in Laravel

Tags: laravel, enums

**Migration** 
In my migration, I have following passed to the database

```
$table->enum('product_name', ['chocolate', 'Candy','biscuits', 'Berry']); 
$table->string('description');
$table->string('product_no');
$table->timestamps();
```

in my model I have this below the fillable and a function to select a choice.

```
protected $fillable =[
      'product_no','description'
    ];
protected $product_name = ['chocolate', 'Candy','biscuits', 'Berry'];

public function getProduct_name()
    {
        return $this->product_name;
    }
```

The problem is I don't know how to handle this in controller and Postman. It is not displaying any error

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [

                'product_no' => 'nullable|product_no',
                'description' => 'required|string',
                           ]);

            $product = new Product();

            $product->product_no = $request->product_no;
            $product->description = $request->description;
            $product->product_name = $request->$model->getProduct_name();

            if (auth()->user()->products()->save($product))
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => $product->toArray()
                ]);
            else
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'product could not be added'
                ], 500);
        }
```

What I intend to achieve is to create a front-end in Angular with a drop down to select the product_name (from the list hard-coded) and description and product_no are fillable. However from Postman, I just entered the values for the three fields i.e. product_name, description and product_no

Comment: `auth()->user()->votes()->save($vote)` Where is `$vote` being defined? This looks like a save method for a `Product`, not a `Vote`.

Comment: It was an error when I was trying to copy the code bit by bit. Thanks for your observation but still not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to replace method and variable names when you copy the `votes` code

```
$product = new Product();
$product->product_no = $request->product_no;
$product->description = $request->description;
$product->product_name = $request->$model->getProduct_name();

if (auth()->user()->votes()->save($vote))
--------------------^^^^^^^-------^^^^^--
    return response()->json([
         'success' => true,
         'data' => $product->toArray()
     ]);
```

That should be

```
if (auth()->user()->products()->save($product))
```

Also there is another field (`product_name`) that you're trying to save but it's not fillable.

```
protected $fillable =[
      'product_no','description', 'product_name'
    ];
```

And also, you may want to consider that using same pattern when naming your variables and methods. You can say `getProductName` or `get_product_name` instead of `getProduct_name`.

Comment: @Payne I just realized and updated my code as well.. You are also need to add `product_name` to fillable columns

Comment: "message": "Undefined variable: model",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myProduct/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php",

Comment: @Payne Ohh you need to remove $ in here `$request->$model->getProduct_name();`

Comment: I should remove $ from model?

Comment: "Call to a member function getProduct_name() on null". What is the essence of the "model"? I just copied it from online

Comment: Umm.. wait.. what ? :) I thought you add that property to request.. I think you shouldn't copy every code on the web.. You need to set $product->product_name value properly ? idk, you may pass to request and say `$product->product_name = $request->product_name`

Comment: But what is the essence of the function in model? protected $product_name = ['chocolate', 'Candy','biscuits', 'Berry'];

public function getProduct_name()
    {
        return $this->product_name;
    } This is what I had before I added "enum type" $product->product_name = $request->product_name